# Grep from pattern file to search in directory not working

Tags: bash, grep

I have a txt file called "optionsList.txt" with lines as such:

```
00201205CA2A421F99B7E0E0B332921C
00AAFF650E9F42B987679AB21F1A5F0F
015CF25A44D047398E96A0BD7A06939E
00201205CA2A421F99B7E0E0B332921C
00AAFF650E9F42B987679AB21F1A5F0F
015CF25A44D047398E96A0BD7A06939E
016F0DFB04A24B5B92E50079CB15ADC7
022F3506A50F451682881080B31F9067
....
```

I am trying to use grep -F -f to find matches in the directory "./Options/"

EDIT: this was the comman I'm using (sorry for not including it earlier):

```
grep -nr -Ff optionsList.txt  ./Options/
```

but the grep comes up with nothing.

When I go a plain pattern grep

```
grep -nr 00AAFF650E9F42B987679AB21F1A5F0F ./Options/
```

I do see proper results like:

```
./Options/ReportOptions.log.25:100331:2017/01/06 04:02:37.479 [7420] 00AAFF650E9F42B987679AB21F1A5F0F: Report.ExecuteJob Start
./Options/ReportOptions.log.25:100348:2017/01/06 04:02:38.988 [7420] 00AAFF650E9F42B987679AB21F1A5F0F: ExecuteAtOnce Before Call
```

Why is my grep command not working for the pattern file?

Comment: what commands have you tried ? do you know which grep is called ?

Comment: Sorry about that. I updated the question to include the command I was using.

Comment: can you check if there is no non printable chars in pattern file: `cat -vte optionsList.txt | head`

Comment: Just an idea, it goes in the same direction as Nahuel: is the optionsList.txt from another OS with different lineending convention?

Comment: Yes it was created in windows. and using the 

    cat -vte optionsList.txt | head

command I can now see that there seems to be some "^M$" character at the end of each line

Comment: I removed the \r character from the line ends. Now it works fabulously. Thank you, sirs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an utility on unix to remove char 13, '\r' or ^M.

Syntax may vary

```
dos2unix optionsList.txt
dos2unix optionsList.txt optionsList.txt
```